# cross domain XML response issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

Ok so I found a plugin from here:

http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

That is supposed to return an xml feed that is not on my local server which would usually not work due to a cross domain policy error. And i'm supposed to be able to use a normal jquery GET call.

I have included the plugin correctly, this is the jquery I am using

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: configXML,
  dataType: "xml",
  error: function(error) {
    alert(error);
  },
  success: function(xml) {
    alert(xml);
  }
});
```

it hits the success alert and says that it is returning an object ... [object Object] .

my problem is that the previous code I used to parse through the xml does not work, its like the xml nodes are not there. Is there a way to see what xml nodes are there? is it even returning xml? when I look in firebug it shows no xml response but a json response for that call, it returns something beginning with this

```
jsonp1265430274350({"query":{"count":"1"
```

any thoughts? thank you

Comment: I can get data.responseText  to come back with some html but i dont want that, data.responseXML doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The site you are requesting is probably not sending the xml content type header nor sending the data in xml format. Have you tried manually requesting the URL with your web browser to confirm the correct data output?